# What is the difference between deficiencies and issues?

Tags: testing

In software testing, are there formal semantics/meanings for the words deficiencies and issues

And what is the difference between these?

Comment: Whatever the organization wants them to mean.  (Just don't ever say "bug"!)

Comment: My opinion is not really an answer since I am not a professional tester, but rather a developer. But my opinion/thought is that an issue would be behavior that someone didn't understand, and a deficiency would be after that issue has been determined wrong behavior as opposed to wrong understanding or misuse. Every deficiency was once an issue, but not every issue is a deficiency. That's just an idea, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I don't think there's a significant difference between those two terms. It could be that specific organizations place specific meanings to differentiate the two, but they both essentially mean that the program isn't doing what it should.

That being said, some organizations use the term "issue" to apply not only to product defects, but also to feature requests and customer support. In other words, an issue for some is synonymous with *a unit of work that we track* whereas a deficiency is simply a defect in the product.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, there really isn't enough of a difference between the two to reliably say there is *any* difference.  It all just depends on where you work and the culture there.  Here at REI, we call a bug an [issue](https://www.google.com/#q=issue) and [deficiency](https://www.google.com/#q=deficiency) simply means that we have a gap that needs to be filled by either a body or a story (we are an agile shop).

This reminds me of the 'severity vs. priority' discussions I have read ad nauseum on the internet and had with co-workers.  The real question (and the most important one) is, what do they mean to *you* and *your team*?